# Symfony2 can't find Route on custom Route Loader

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-routing

I'm having the same problem symfony2 is describing [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html)

> This comes in handy when you have a bundle but don't want to manually
>   add the routes for the bundle to `app/config/routing.yml`. This may be
>   especially important when you want to make the bundle reusable

TLDR; im trying to implement a custom Route Loader using this part of the symfony2 documentation 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html#more-advanced-loaders

However it doesn't seem to be working, the route cannot be found;

This is what I've tried so far: 
The loader:

```
<?php
//namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Routing;
namespace Gabriel\AdminPanelBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class AdvancedLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();

        $resource = '@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml';
        $type = 'yaml';

        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource, $type);

        $collection->addCollection($importedRoutes);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return $type === 'advanced_extra';
    }
}
```

here is my routing.yml

```
located in: src/Gabriel/AdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
```

the routing.yml

```
gabriel_admin_panel:
    resource: "@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /superuser
```

The Routes of the bundle can't be found unless I put the Routes back in the main app/config/routing.yml file, how to fix this?

Edit:

> FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException: Circular reference
>   detected in "/app/config/routing_dev.yml"
>   ("/app/config/routing_dev.yml" > "/app/config/routing.yml" > "." >
>   "@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Controller/" >
>   "/app/config/routing_dev.yml").

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you clear cache? You can use `app/console router:debug` to check all routes available

Comment: I cleared the cache and router:debug doesn't show the route, I put that configuration above 'gabriel_admin_panel' from the main app/config/routing.yml directly into the Gabriel/AdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml is this right?

Comment: Yes, it is. After some tests, I found the answer. Take a look below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also configure service

```
# src/Gabriel/AdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
your_bundle.routing_loader:
    class: Gabriel\AdminPanelBundle\Routing\AdvancedLoader
    tags:
        - { name: routing.loader }
```

And routing file

```
# app/config/routing.yml
YourBundle_extra:
    resource: .
    type: advanced_extra
```

Comment: yes but I will give you best answer since this is another type of error